# Azure DB Tableview to Android with Azure Mobile Services Offline sync

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services, azureportal

I have created a tableview in Azure DB,  Where Foo and Foo2 are joined,

How do i query this (table)view from Azure DB to an android application with azure mobile services offline sync?

**Documentation used:** 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data

Answer (score 0):

Azure Mobile Offline sync allows client users to interact with the mobile app even there is no network connection. Changes are stored in a local data store and these changes could sync with the remote back end when the network connection is online.

> How do i query this (table)view from Azure DB to an android application with azure mobile services offline sync?

For the online table, you could define your table instance as follows in your mobile client and directly communicate with your remote table.

```
MobileServiceTable<ToDoItem> mToDoTable = mClient.getTable(ToDoItem.class);
```

For the offline cache table, you define the reference as follows:

```
MobileServiceSyncTable<ToDoItem> mToDoTable = mClient.getSyncTable("ToDoItem", ToDoItem.class);
```

At this point, you would query against your local database. In order to sync the records from the remote table to your local table, you need to execute the Pull operation for a specific table. And you could execute the Push operation to push all changes (cross multiple tables) in your local database to your remote database. Details you could follow [How to use the Azure Mobile Apps SDK for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#offline-sync). Also, I would recommend you read [Offline Data Sync in Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync) for better understanding of Azure Mobile Apps Offline Data Sync.